# How can I transform a dataset in a graph database?

Tags: java, neo4j, ontology

I am developing a software that has to transform a dataset in a graph database.

So far I have developed the dataset import. Basically, I open the file and afterward it is displayed in the **tab1** and stored in a matrix of Objects.

Now, I don't have any idea on how to convert it in a graph database, and above all, I don't know how to map the dataset to the following ontology:

[image: DM2_common_patterns]

To be clearer I want to give a semantic to the dataset, mapping it to the specific ontology (for example, each element of the first column has to be under the node "elements" and the property that links each field of the first column to each field of the second column is under the node of "tuple"). In a nutshell, I have to link each field with the element of the same row. The first element, the second element, and the property that link both of them have to be linked to the specific part of the ontology.

How can I implement it, and which Java constructs I should study in order to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the actual import you would create Cypher statements and run those on the database to create the nodes and relationships. For semantically correct node, relationship and property names, you just have to build the Cypher statements with those desired labels.

Comment: Look at http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/06/fun-with-facebook-in-neo4j_19.html for a simple example of that.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could use http://gist.neo4j.org/ to prototype your thoughts?